# Apache httpclient 4.5.2 not sending POST data on retry via ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy

Tags: httpclient

I have setup the HttpClient with ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy. I am making a POST call to the server with JSON payload in InputStreamEntity.

When server returns with "503 Service Unavailable" the retry strategy kicks in and makes another request after a delay read from Retry-After header.

I have enabled the logs and what I observe is, in the first request the JSON payload is sent properly. But on the retry request no payload is sent to the server and I am receiving a "400 Bad Request".

I wonder why the payload is not sent on the retry request. In my implementation of ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy I am not messing anything with HttpResponse or HttpContext. Is it because that once the content is read from InputStreamEntity, the Entity looses the data?

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

- thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually with InputStreamEntity, which is a non-repeatable Entity. This means its content cannot be read more than once. So on retry the original Entity content was lost.

When I use a repeatable Enity like ByteArrayEntity, the issue was solved.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e119